# calculate count of certain cells using vba in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have build a quiz and displaying score using some checks and output cells have "1" if ans correct and "0" if wrong.

to calculate score I use the function

```
=COUNTIF(S7:S158,1)
```

Problem is the score gets updated as soon user starts writing ans.

I want to have a Macro SUBMIT(using form control) which when clicked gives the score.

what should i write in Sub SUBMIT() so as to execute the above function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write fomula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(S7:S158)=x;COUNTIF(S7:S158,1);"")
```

where **x** is a number of questions (for example 100). So, function **COUNTA** counts number of non empty cells in the range, and if the user ansered on **all** questions, condition `COUNTA(S7:S158)=x` becames true and the `COUNTIF(S7:S158,1)` calculated, otherwise an empty string is displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following code in `Workbook_Open`

```
Sheet1.EnableCalculation = False
```

In `Sub Submit()`

```
Sheet1.EnableCalculation = True
Sheet1.Calculate
```

For more, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841201.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer and I resort to macro only when all options are exhausted. This is mainly for the benefit of people that might want use/reuse it for other purposes. But that's just my preference.

You can have a cell with a label of **Show Score** and accepts **Yes/No** and put an `IF` around your `=COUNTIF(S7:S158,1)`.

Comment: Uhm, this is really basic Excel. Type "Show Score" into one cell. That's your label. Next to it, use data validation with the list option and enter yes and no as two values separated with a comma like "yes,no".